# Best way for multiple layouts on Meteor

Tags: meteor

Recently we have started using `Meteor` for our apps, but we didn't want to use same layout for all mobile (android and ios) and browser views.

Is there any best way or good practices to build different layouts for multiple platforms without having to duplicate all `/server` and `packages` again in different projects? I mean, keeping everything  on same place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't have to duplicate the `server` or anything else but the `client` folder content. The way I understand it, as long as you use a meteor client, the server side is agnostic of what the client specifically is.

Let's say you want a desktop bootstrap version of your app, and an ionic version for mobile. You just need to route the client on the right `client` subfolder (`bootstrap` or `ionic`) in the Meteor startup code for client depending on their user agent.

Unless you plan to use dedicated servers for each (meaning it would be like two different apps connecting to the same mongo database) there is no way to split everything in two versions and keep it as a single app (i.e. both mobile and desktop clients are handled by the same meteor server process).

Bottom-line: if, after evaluating it, you consider that the delta in the amount of client side code sent is two big between a dedicated version and a multipurpose version (or to rephrase it, the useless packages weight too much), then make two different servers and handle the redirection in a third. If not, keep two different clients working with the same server

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Billybobbonnet! As I could understand, I should have multiple `client` folders. But woudn't this imply in bigger code for each platform, and useless code? I dont know, lets say I have 4 platforms. For each of them, `client` folder would have 4 times the number of needed files to run it, is it right?

Comment: Sorry, I have just re-read your "Bottom-line" text.. So I imagine there is no automatic or "easy" way to manage multiple UI interfaces, right?

Comment: you are right, as far as I know. This kind of problem must be quantified. You need to assess what is the difference in size between the refined and complete set before avoiding this kind of approach by principle (at least at first). You need to balance it with the time you would spend to make 2 different servers. In an ideal world, if you had all the time/money you need, I would advise duplicating the whole thing. Again, pragmatically, I think you need to assess to extra weight and decide on the ratio between it and development time.